# Columnstore Aggregate Pushdown doesn't work for float/real data types

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, aggregate, columnstore

I am having an issue with Aggregate Pushdown for `float/real` data types. 
 According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance), Aggregate Pushdown is supported for "Any datatype <= 64 bits" or 8 bytes ():

> - Supported aggregate operators are MIN, MAX, SUM, COUNT, AVG
> - Any datatype <= 64 bits is supported. For example, bigint is supported as its size is 8 bytes but decimal (38,6) is not because its size is 17 bytes. Also, no string types are supported
> - Aggregate operator must be on top of SCAN node or SCAN node with group by

It doesn't work no matter what I do. I tried making column nullable and not null. Grouping and w/o grouping.

We are running on the latest version of the SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3). I wonder anyone experienced the same? It seems like a bug to me. Am I missing anything?

If you experience the same issue, please [upvote my SQL Server Feedback Request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38916988-add-aggregate-pushdown-for-float-columns-in-column). Now I am faced with a choice to convert `float` columns to `numeric`. But operations with `numeric` types are slower in general. So I may gain in one place and lose in another. I have successfully tested `numeric(15,12)`.

Here is a script illustrating the issue (please enable Actual Execution plan to see the issue):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TestTable;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable 
(
     cKey             INT               NOT NULL
   , cGroup           INT               NOT NULL
   , cNumeric36_3     NUMERIC(36, 3)    NULL
   , cNumeric18_3     DECIMAL(18, 3)    NULL
   , cNumeric18_9     DECIMAL(18, 9)    NULL
   , cNumeric15_12    DECIMAL(15, 12)   NULL
   , cMoney           MONEY             NULL
   , cFloat53         FLOAT(53)         NULL
   , cFloat53Less1    FLOAT(53)         NULL
   , cFloat24         FLOAT(24)         NULL
   , cReal            REAL              NULL
);

;WITH _Numbers0 AS (
    SELECT TOP 3000  column_id  FROM  sys.all_columns 
)
, _Numbers AS (
    SELECT cKey = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM _Numbers0 a CROSS JOIN _Numbers0 b
)
, _Keys AS (
    SELECT
            cKey = n.cKey
          , Divder10    = CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 10))
          , Divder100   = CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 100))
          , Divder10000 = CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 10000))
    FROM _Numbers n
)
, _RandomValues AS 
(
    SELECT 
          cKey  
        , cGroup        = ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100          
        , cNumeric36_3  = CONVERT(NUMERIC(36,3) , CHECKSUM(NewId())           )                         / CONVERT(NUMERIC(36,3) , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
        , cNumeric18_3  = CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,3) , CHECKSUM(NewId())           )                         / CONVERT(NUMERIC(36,3) , NULLIF(Divder100            , 0.00))
        , cNumeric18_9  = CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,9) , CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 1000000 )                         / CONVERT(NUMERIC(36,3) , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
        , cNumeric15_12 = CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,12), CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 100     )                         / CONVERT(NUMERIC(36,3) , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
        , cMoney        = CONVERT(MONEY, CHECKSUM(NewId()))                                             / CONVERT(MONEY         , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
        , cFloat53      = CONVERT(FLOAT, CHECKSUM(NewId())) * CONVERT(FLOAT, CHECKSUM(NewId()))         / CONVERT(FLOAT(53)     , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
        , cFloat53Less1 = CONVERT(FLOAT, 1.00)                                                          / CONVERT(FLOAT(53)     , NULLIF(CHECKSUM(NewId())    , 0.00))
        , cFloat24      = CONVERT(FLOAT(24), CHECKSUM(NewId())) * CONVERT(FLOAT(24), CHECKSUM(NewId())) / CONVERT(FLOAT(24)     , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
        , cReal         = CONVERT(REAL, CHECKSUM(NewId())) * CONVERT(REAL, CHECKSUM(NewId()))           / CONVERT(REAL          , NULLIF(Divder10000          , 0.00))
    FROM _Keys
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable 
SELECT *       
FROM _RandomValues
GO

CHECKPOINT;
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IDXCC_dboTestTable
    ON dbo.TestTable WITH (MAXDOP = 4);
GO

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.TestTable tt
GO

SELECT MAX(tt.cNumeric36_3) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cNumeric18_3) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cNumeric18_9) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cNumeric15_12) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cMoney) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cFloat53) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cFloat53Less1) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cFloat24) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
SELECT MAX(tt.cReal) FROM dbo.TestTable tt;
GO
```

Comment: We are on SQL Server 2017-CU17 and there is still no support for floats :(. 
They also removed my Connect bug, so I created a new one on the Azure feedback site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft has updated the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-2017) to say that float is not supported*.

The documentation for aggregate pushdown was inaccurate in some places and it doesn't state all of the restrictions. In some testing that I did a week ago I also found that float types are not supported. In addition to that, `numeric(10,0)` is supported despite requiring nine bytes of storage. Here's the most accurate summary for supported data types that I'm aware of:

> All date and time data types are supported except `datetimeoffset`. All exact numeric data types are supported if they are under 10 bytes.

If you want to troubleshoot more you may be able to uncover something with the `query_execution_dynamic_push_down_statistics` extended event.

In case it's of interest, you can read about some of the limitations I've found around aggregate pushdown in my blog post [here](https://erikdarlingdata.com/2017/07/aggregate-pushdown-limitations/). Paul White has also written about the details of [Grouped Aggregate Pushdown](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/04/sql-plan/grouped-aggregate-pushdown).

---

* Float and real now appear to work with aggregate pushdown for `COUNT` and `COUNT_BIG` only in SQL Server 2017 CU 16 (and maybe earlier). Other previously-unsupported types like datetimeoffset and numeric with precision > 18 also work, so long as the data (in batch format) fits in 64 bits *at runtime*.