# Columnstore Aggregate Pushdown doesn´t work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, aggregate, columnstore

Recently I started investigating columnstore indexes for some warehouse-behaving part of our system.

What I can´t achieve yet is to make [aggregate pushdown](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/columnstore-index-performance-sql-server-2016-aggregate-pushdown) work. I've checked data types and all requirements, but still it doesn't work.
Just to be sure, I just ran query from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182296/columnstore-aggregate-pushdown-doesnt-work-for-float-real-data-types) and I see that execution plans for all data-types are exactly the same.

The version of SQL Server is SP1-CU5.

Do you know what else could I check?

update: I think I got it, I have Standard edition and this is one of [standard edition limitations](http://www.nikoport.com/2016/11/20/columnstore-indexes-part-91-sql-server-2016-standard-edition-limitations).

Comment: Roman, is it a specific query that does not work? or do all queries lose the aggregate pushdown? Can you run the queries from CISL to see if your tables are all supporting it? https://github.com/NikoNeugebauer/CISL

Comment: It doesn't work for any query as far as I can tell. Thanks for the hint, I'll try these queries!

Comment: Let us know what the results are, then we can start troubleshooting further from there on.

Comment: @StijnWynants which query can show 'if mytables are all supporting it'?

Comment: I've tried everything but I cannot see this 'Actual number of locally aggregated rows' in the plan. This is probably some traceflag, but the one which disables aggregate pushdowns (9354) is not set.

Comment: Please post a self answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple, I should've read more about limitations. The problem is that I have Standard edition and this is one of [standard edition limitations](http://www.nikoport.com/2016/11/20/columnstore-indexes-part-91-sql-server-2016-standard-edition-limitations).